# Angular click event not working - tried many solutions

Tags: angular, typescript

I have click events on my main single page that work as expected.  However, I have a subcomponent within that page that displays a table with rows.  Each row has a button to select that row and emit it.  For some reason, my row select button doesn't work. The main component is Rooms and the component within is Rooms-list.

rooms-list.component.html

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Even/Odd</th>
            <th>Room Number</th>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th>Room Price</th>
            <th>Room Amenities</th>
            <th>Check-In Time</th>
            <th>Check-Out Time</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Select Room</th>
        </tr>
        <tr [ngClass]="e? 'even' : 'odd'" 
        *ngFor="let room of rooms;  let e = even; let o = odd; let i = index;">
            <td>{{ i | percent }}</td>
            <td>{{ e ? "Even" : "Odd" }}</td>
            <td>{{ room.roomNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ room.roomType }}</td>
            <td>{{ room.price | currency : 'GBP' }}</td>
            <td>{{ room.amenities | lowercase }}</td>
            <td>{{ room.checkinTime | date }}</td>
            <td>{{ room.checkoutTime | date }}</td>
            <td>{{ room.rating | number: '1.0-0' }}</td>
            <td><button (click)="selectRoom(room)">Select</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

rooms-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter,Input, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges  } from '@angular/core';
import { RoomList } from '../rooms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RoomsComponent } from '../rooms.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'hinv-rooms-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RoomsComponent],
  templateUrl: './rooms-list.component.html',
  styleUrl: './rooms-list.component.scss'
})

export class RoomsListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() rooms: RoomList[] = [];

  @Output() selectedRoom = new EventEmitter<RoomList>();

  constructor(){}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    
  }

  selectRoom(room: RoomList): void{
    console.log('clicked');
    this.selectedRoom.emit(room);
  }

  
};
```

I also tried a button that called a function without parameters and that did not work either. I don't know if it matters but I'm running Angular 17 (whatever is current). I also looked at many solutions here on SE as well as "how to" and it seems like I've got everything in order - yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Any error messages or screenshot from logs will be helpful. Do you have your table poplulated?

Comment: Table is populated, no errors.  When I use my browser dev tools and set a breakpoint on the selectRoom function, the function is never called.  I do get one error but I think it's more a warning related to the html:

ERROR Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <tr> but found <tbody>.

Angular expected this DOM:

<table _ngcontent-ng-c1432761322="" class="table">
  <tr>…</tr>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
  …
</table>

Comment: and then it says Angular hydrated 4 component(s) and 27 node(s), 0 component(s) were skipped.

Comment: But I don't declare tbody anywhere which is strange.

Comment: Well this is wild.  I figured it out but it doesn't make sense.  When I view the HTML, angular automatically added the tbody tags.  So, for a "what the heck" I added them myself and suddenly the button worked.  It makes no sense.  Angular fixes it, it doesn't work.  I fix it, it works.